# K-Means Clustering with R MARKDOWN

Tags: r, r-markdown, cluster-analysis, k-means

I work for big a fashion retailer and I am creating clusters of customers depending on their purchase patterns. I perform this clustering using K-Means in a RMarkdown file, to be able to run an "automated" report weekly.

**My issue** is that if a specific customer has been assigned to cluster 1 by the algorithm, I can run the same report using the same data again, and the same customer can be assigned to cluster 4 instead. The assignment of cluster number seems to be random, although the exact same clusters will be calculated. This gives me problems in describing these clusters to a normal person in an automated way.

Is there a way to assign customers the same cluster every time I run the report based on a logic with K-means?

normal kmeans clustering

Comment: Setting the random number generating seed with `set.seed(1234567)` (you can replace the number with a different integer if you like) will make it so running the cluster analysis with same data will generate the same clusters every time.

Comment: Another issue I'd highlight with the workflow is that, even with setting the seed as @DaveArmstrong suggested, cluster profiles can change week to week as the data changes if the structure of the data changes. And even if it doesn't, the number assignment of the clusters (cluster 1, cluster 2, etc) can change from week to week for the same profiles because the k-means algorithm assigns those membership values arbitrarily.

Comment: Perhaps a better method is to first create a "final" cluster analysis on all the data that you have, and then create a classification model (i.e. a typing tool) whose algorithm would predict the cluster membership of new data, and use that model in your rmarkdown document instead.

Comment: @Phil you are correct. In my case, I am looking at data across 2 years (active customer base), and because of this, the clusters and how they will be described week by week, will be somewhat stable.

Comment: Still the issue of randomized cluster assignments, i.e. what is cluster 1 in one week can be cluster 3 the next week.

Comment: Unless you have something in your code that identifies cluster profiles and rename them accordingly.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong well I see a problem here, and its because of details I didnt include in the post, my bad. I will run all Online sales transactions from 2 years (active customer base) roughly 10M transactions. Each week a few new transactions will be added (but small in comparison to all "old" data).  But we will still have the same cluster groups and these will be described in an automated way (average transactions, average spend, size of total revenue etc.). I just need the VIP customers for example to always be in cluster 1 to describe them automatically in the reporting.

Comment: For that, then ... look at the results from the cluster and reassign the actual cluster numbers based on the VIP customers you want to see in cluster 1.